# Disable verify_exists on models.URLField at runtime?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How can I temporarily turn off verify_exists on a models.URLField at runtime?  I would like to skip the check on certain URLs (they block EC2 IPs from their firewall).

I'm interfacing with the model through the ModelForm right now.

Answer (score 0):

```
   class F(forms.Form):
    url_field = forms.URLField(verify_exists = True)

form = F({"url_field":"http://blaghblagh.net"})
form.base_fields['url_field'].verify_exists = False
form.is_valid() # returns True
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Could it be that this is a ModelForm and verify_exists is set in the Model?